# c# import multiple worksheets into one datatable

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel file with many worksheets. Each worksheet has 5 columns,but the number of rows are different. I want to import each worksheet, one after one, into a single datatable. So if my file contains 10 worksheets, then my datatable should contain 50 columns.
This is what I tried:

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            int i = 1; 
            foreach (var ws in pck.Workbook.Worksheets)
            {
                foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column) + i); i++;
                }
                var startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;
                for (int rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
                {
                    var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
                    DataRow row = dt.Rows.Add();
                    foreach (var cell in wsRow)
                    {
                        row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
                    }
                } 
            }
```

but it puts next worksheet data after last row not after last column in my datatable.

Comment: **Assuming** I understood, you pretty much want to "flatten" everything, so why even use a DataTable? Just parse each "item" into some collection (Array, List). If you want to stick to a DataTable, and assuming the data isn't "large", then just keep adding columns (dynamically). In your code above, you're adding a new `Row` "for each worksheet".

Comment: can you show me how